# How to solve 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes' problem with CSV upload in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, read-csv

I tried all existing in Stack Overflow methods how to solve problem with uploading csv using

```
    pandas
    (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated 
    \UXXXXXXXX escape (<command-1157388712454537>, line 1)
     File <command-1157388712454537>:1

     df = pd.read_csv('C:\Users\eleps\Downloads\export.csv')

     print(df)
```

Still no luck. Does anyone have any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: `pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\eleps\\Downloads\\export.csv')`